# use a foreign key or keep data for transactional historical information?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Here is a scenario.

You have an ecommerce website which sells to customers.
There are transactions obviously
e.g.  For every sale you record information about the sale.
So lets have have a 'purchases' table.
What columns should it have?

1) Should it have just a foreign key to 'customer' table using 'customer_id'?
OR
2) Keep a snapshot such as 'customer_name', 'customer_address'...both as VARCHAR(x)
OR 
3) BOTH
OR
4) separate the 'purchase' table into multiple tables?
OR
something else.

Please give your opinion and why.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time is an inherent concept of your problem domain - and with ecommerce, it is - you should treat this as a first-class design concept in your schema, too.

My preferred option is to have a "validity period" indicator on tables that can change over time. For instance, here is what the customer table might look like:

```
CUSTOMER
---------------
CustomerID   pk
RecordVersion pk
Name
EmailAddress
HomeAddressID fk
HomeAddressRecordVersion fk
ValidFrom
ValidUntil
```

The "purchases" table then joins to the customers table by specifying both the customerID and RecordVersion columns. That way, if you want to see what email address the customer was using at the time they placed the order, you can retrieve that data from the customer table.

You will know the other email addresses that customer has used, not just because you can find that in some purchase data, but because it's a part of your record of the customer.

This model can become quite complex, and hard to query - so use it sparingly. But especially for products, prices, discounts, delivery addresses etc. it is very useful esp. in ecommerce solutions.

Comment: This approach sounds a great approach compared to storing the snapshot. It really keeps the time dimension of the data relevant. I guess, like you said the queries will be more complex and one should look at creating a library of functions that do that for you in a centralised location. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the columns the Purchases table should have it depends a lot on your requirements. Usually you would have some sort of purchase code, purchase date and purchase customer as a minimal, plus a list of items in the purchase (separate table).

Regarding the options you mention, I am guessing here you have a relational database and did not go for a NoSQL solution.

In that case I would discard options (2). It does not fit well into a relational schema, since you would be potentially duplicating the customer information in several records. For the same reason I would also discard option (3).

Option (1) is the one that fits better in a relational database approach. You would have purchases, each of them linked to its own customer. This allow you to easily know:

- which purchases a given customer has made.
- which customer has made a concrete purchase.
- Make purchase searches based on customers given by some criteria.
- Make customer searches based on purchases given by some criteria.
- etc.

If you need to be able to record the customer data in a given date, you could always opt for creating a customer history table and link it to the Customer table. Given a purchase date you could then know which customer data was "active" when the purchase was made.

About option (4), I do not know what you mean so I can not answer that.

HTH